# Get all XML attribute values on same level in XDocument with c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following XML

[image: XML]

What I need is to get all values of the "condition" attribute for each "cascadingentity" section in the XML on the same level from the XDocument XML

In this case the result should be

clm_bankingrelationship.clm_agreementid
clm_bankingrelationship.clm_bankingrelationshipid

I'e tried already various ways but either I get all values of all existing decendants (levels) or just the first. What I need is the values of the first elements on the same level.

Any hint is reall appreciated.

Thx

EDIT:

Here the XML:

```
<rootentity name='clm_bankingrelationship'>
    <cascadingentities>
        <cascadingentity name='clm_agreement'>
            <fetchXML>
                <fetch distinct='true'>
                    <entity name='clm_agreement' >
                        <attribute name='clm_agreementid' />
                        <filter type='and'>
                          <condition attribute='clm_agreementid' operator='eq' value='{clm_bankingrelationship.clm_agreementid}' />
                        </filter>
                    </entity>
                </fetch>
            </fetchXML>
            <cascadingentities>
                <cascadingentity name='clm_partneragreementbanking'>
                    <fetchXML>
                        <fetch distinct='true'>
                            <entity name='clm_partneragreementbanking' >
                                <attribute name='clm_partneragreementbankingid' />
                                <link-entity name="clm_role" from="clm_roleid" to="clm_roleid" link-type="inner" />
                                <filter type='and' >
                                  <condition attribute='clm_agreementid' operator='eq' value='{clm_agreement.clm_agreementid}' />
                                </filter>
                            </entity>
                        </fetch>
                    </fetchXML>
                </cascadingentity>                                              
                <cascadingentity name='account'>
                    <fetchXML>
                        <fetch distinct="true" >
                            <entity name="account" >
                                <attribute name="accountid" />
                                <link-entity name="clm_partneragreementbanking" from="clm_partnerid" to="accountid" link-type="inner" />
                                <filter type='and' >
                                    <condition entityname="clm_partneragreementbanking" attribute="clm_agreementid" operator="eq" value='{clm_agreement.clm_agreementid}' />
                                    <condition attribute='clm_mainpartnertypecd' operator='neq' value='858000005' />
                                </filter>
                            </entity>
                        </fetch>
                    </fetchXML>                         
                </cascadingentity>
            </cascadingentities>
        </cascadingentity>
        <cascadingentity name='clm_waiver'>
            <fetchXML>
                <fetch distinct='true'>
                    <entity name='clm_waiver' >
                        <attribute name='clm_waiverid' />
                        <filter type='and' >
                          <condition attribute='clm_bankingrelationshipid' operator='eq' value='{clm_bankingrelationship.clm_bankingrelationshipid}' />
                        </filter>
                    </entity>
                </fetch>
            </fetchXML>                         
        </cascadingentity>
    </cascadingentities>
</rootentity>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML as text so we can try out a solution?

Comment: shure sorry, added as update of the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath to get those values:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(PATH_TO_XML);
var conditions = xml.XPathEvaluate("rootentity/cascadingentities/cascadingentity/" 
                                 + "fetchXML/fetch/entity/filter/condition");
var values = ((IEnumerable<object>)conditions).OfType<XElement>()
                 .Select(e => e.Attribute("value").Value.Trim('{', '}'));
```

See it in action [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TzLmow).

Comment: Awesome, you are my hero ;)  works lika a charm, thank you very much :)